# User got access to oauth token? than how to secure it?

Tags: node.js, ajax, facebook, api, oauth

Currently we are looking to develop oauth authentication for my API.
So basically our UI will be in reactjs which will show TV Grid schedule using nodejs API At backend which will return JSON. We will handle UI changes via ajax.

On ajax or on page load we will call API to display TV Grid.

So we want to secure API using oauth.
Lets say I have passed APP ID & client secret key and received the "auth_token" with callback URL and everything (like fb, google has it)
that will stored on localstorage or cookies.
If attackers get access to that token and he can call API get access to data.
How can I avoid data theft?
Is there something I am missing in oauth? please let me know.

Comment: You may find these useful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Comment: Thanks :) this is useful but still token on client side adds risk of theft ? If I get token I can impersonate isn't it?

Comment: If an attacker gets their hands on whatever provides access, they get access ... same as if someone was able to steal your car keys, they would be able to get inside your car. So, don’t let your car keys get stolen then ...

Comment: Yes correct. Thats what I am asking how can we make it secure?